# Finding Height and Width of Polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1

I have been asked by my employer to take a shapefile and produce a table that shows the height and width (in meters) of each polygon in a shapefile. I have explored the calculate geometry option and the only options it produces is area, perimeter and coordinates of centroid. I have also tried using the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool but this does not produce the result I want either.

Below is an example image of the shapefile. To be clear, I am interested in finding the height and width of each individual polygon.

[image: Habitat Polygons]

Comment: can you clarify more what do you mean by polygon height? and polygon width? if their shapes are irregular! (other words) can you specify what you look for (an example for one polygon)?

Comment: If polygon is not a rectangle, such things depend on definition. I'd say the best is length is the one of medial axis. Width is area / above.

Comment: Why do you say that Minimum Bounding Geometry tool does not produce the result you want? The envelope often referred to as the minimum bounding box for a polygon would give you it's width and height. You need to explain in your question why this is not sufficient. Because as I see it that is the answer. Suggest you go back and edit your question with more information.